# Magento2 grid action popup

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to popup an action on click of button in adminhtml grid instead of redirecting the page?
I am using custom class (class EmailLogActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column)

Comment: Did you found smth for this?